# Fully convolutional network - different size of images in training data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to model a fully convolutional neural network using the Keras library, Tensorflow backend.

The issue I face is that of feeding ]differently sized images in batches to `model.fit()` function. The training set consists of images of different sizes varying from 768x501 to 1024x760.

Not more than 5 images have the same dimensions, so grouping them into batches seems to be of no help.

Numpy allows storing the data in a single variable in list form. But the keras `model.fit()` function throws an error on receiving a list type training array.

I do not wish to resize and lose the data as I already have a very small dataset.

How do I go about training this network?

Comment: You can try and pad the smaller images so that they have the same size as the largest image. If that is not a valid solution for you, try reading [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/85). Towards the end someone poses the same question as you.

Comment: Why don't you want to resize the data? How many images do you have?

Comment: I have just about 1200 images for training. Some are of 1024x(~650), and some are 768x(~520). So what I have done is split them into two batches and trained the model using them. I did not want to resize because I wanted purely unaltered data to be used. But it seems like this is the only way to go, or padding.

Comment: So, I am training a fully convolutional network. Image in image out type. So my output images are of the same size as my input. What I dont understand is that, I have trained using input shape as (None, None, 1). Using two batches of training images - 1024x680 and 760x520. But when I feed an input of size 1024x720, it predicts an output of the size 1024x680, which corresponds to one of my training batch sizes. How do I go about creating a network that can be fed an input image of any size to produce the desired output - an image of the same size as the input image.

Comment: resizing or crop is the way to go.

Comment: @Blue can you show us the code you used to train and predict?
It seems weird that a purely convolutional network transforms the shape of your image.

Answer (score 2):

I think *Spatial Pyramid Pooling (SPP)* might be helpful. Checkout this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729).

> We note that SPP has several remarkable properties for deep CNNs:
>
> 1) SPP is able to generate a fixed-length output regardless of the input size, while the sliding window pooling used in the previous deep networks cannot;
>
> 2) SPP uses multi-level spatial bins, while the sliding window pooling uses only a single window size. Multi-level pooling has been shown to be robust to object deformations;
>
> 3) SPP can pool features extracted at variable scales thanks to the flexibility of input scales. Through experiments we show that all these factors elevate the recognition accuracy of deep networks.

`yhenon` has implemented [SPP for Keras on Github](https://github.com/yhenon/keras-spp).